# Creating a new &str

Tags: rust

I want to map over a vector of str so that it reproduces other values:

```
let v = vec!["str1", "str2", "str3", "str4"]
let res = v.map_in_place(|x| x + "__") // error: binary operation `+` cannot be applied to type `&str`
```

Note that I don't need to **change** `x`, I need to create a **new** `&str` by adding a new string literal to `x`. How can I do that?

Comment: @jgillich, `concat!` only works with literals, not variables.

Comment: You may find this useful: http://chrismorgan.info/blog/rust-fizzbuzz.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert `x` to a `String` before you can do `+` on it, like `x.to_string() + "__"`, but, there's another problem with your code:

The type of `v` here is `Vec<&str>` and `map_in_place` expects the type of the resulting type to be of the same size (and alignment) as the original, and the size of `&str` is not the same as `String`, so it fails at runtime - [Demo](http://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20v%20%3D%20vec![%22str1%22%2C%20%22str2%22%2C%20%22str3%22%2C%20%22str4%22]%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20res%20%3D%20v.map_in_place%28%7Cx%7C%20x.to_string%28%29%20%2B%20%22__%22%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20res%29%3B%0A%7D).

There are several possible changes to make this work:

If you really want to use `map_in_place`, you could declare `v` as:

```
let v = vec!["str1".to_string(), "str2".to_string(), "str3".to_string(), "str4".to_string()];
```

[Demo](http://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20v%20%3D%20vec![%22str1%22.to_string%28%29%2C%20%22str2%22.to_string%28%29%2C%20%22str3%22.to_string%28%29%2C%20%22str4%22.to_string%28%29]%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20res%20%3D%20v.map_in_place%28%7Cx%7C%20x%20%2B%20%22__%22%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20res%29%3B%0A%7D)

Another way would be to use `into_iter().map(...).collect()`, which will immediately free the original vector after creating the new one.

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec!["str1", "str2", "str3", "str4"];
    let res = v.into_iter().map(|x| x.to_string() + "__").collect::<Vec<_>>();
    println!("{}", res);
}
```

Output:

```
[str1__, str2__, str3__, str4__]
```

[Demo](http://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20v%20%3D%20vec![%22str1%22%2C%20%22str2%22%2C%20%22str3%22%2C%20%22str4%22]%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20res%20%3D%20v.into_iter%28%29.map%28%7Cx%7C%20x.to_string%28%29%20%2B%20%22__%22%29.collect%3A%3A%3CVec%3C_%3E%3E%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20res%29%3B%0A%7D)

Comment: and if I want to return a vec of &str, do I have to convert each of the member again back to &str?

Comment: You can't return a `Vec<&str>` if you dynamically allocated the strings in your function, as you're doing here. You need to return a `Vec<String>`. A `&str` points inside a string that exists somewhere else, and the compiler must know where it comes from and who is responsible for freeing it. (In the case of string literals, nobody is responsible for freeing them, because they're statically allocated in the executable, hence `'static`.) `String` means "I own a dynamically allocated string", so it is responsible for freeing the string's contents.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the memory has to be owned by someone. In the case of your literals, they're written into your binary directly. But when you want to add the two literals together, that isn't going to work. You're going to need to make some `String`s to represent the actual owning structure, and then if you really want to work with an vector of slices, make one from that vector. Does that make sense?